# Obejctive C: Recursion(?) within Controller

Tags: objective-c, nswindowcontroller

I have got a problem with my WindowController for an App that's basically a list of items, sitting on a panel that can be opened from the menu bar.

To open the panel the user has to click on the App's Status item in the menubar. The app loads fine and everything works ok if the panel is open from the start (and you don't click the status item). However, if its hidden at launch and one clicks the statusitem to open the panel, the App starts eating away huge chunks of RAM without ever getting out of the loop that is creating this effect.

I have worked with some breakpoints to try to find the problem. It seems that some methods within my Window Controller keep calling each other creating an endless loop. But I can't figure out why.
Maybe one of you guys can spot the problem. If any other lines of code are of interest I will try to get them to you. However, for now this is the heart of the application. The rest does not contain that much logic (apart from the AppDelegate).

Here's the Controller's .m-file:

```
//
//  UIController.m
//  hourglass
//
//  Created by Matze on 24/04/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 hourglass. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UIController.h"

@implementation UIController

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<UIControllerDelegate>)delegate {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"UI"];
    if (self != nil) {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)deleteSelectedObjects {
    NSArray *objectArray = [_Tasks selectedObjects];

    for (int i = 0; i < [objectArray count]; i++) {
        NSManagedObject *mo2delete = [objectArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] deleteObject: mo2delete];
    }
}

#pragma Actions
- (IBAction)buttonDelete:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger row = [TableView rowForView:sender];
    [TableView selectRowIndexes:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:row] byExtendingSelection:NO];

    [self deleteSelectedObjects];
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    unichar key = [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0];

    if(key == NSDeleteCharacter)
    {
        if([TableView selectedRow] == -1)
        {
            NSBeep();
        }

        BOOL isEditing = [[NSApp delegate]isEditing];

        if (!isEditing)
        {
            [self deleteSelectedObjects];
            return;
        }

    }

    [super keyDown:event];
}

#pragma UI Drawing & Animation

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Create Panel
    NSPanel *panel = (id)[self window];
    [panel setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [panel setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
    [panel setOpaque:NO];
    [panel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

    // Resize Panel
    NSRect panelRect = [[self window] frame];
    panelRect.size.height = POPUP_HEIGHT;
    [[self window] setFrame:panelRect display:NO];
}

- (NSRect)statusRectForWindow:(NSWindow *)window {
    NSRect screenRect = [[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    NSRect statusRect = NSZeroRect;

    statusItemView = nil;
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(statusItemViewForUIController:)]) {
        statusItemView = [[self delegate] statusItemViewForUIController:self];
    }

    if (statusItemView) {
        statusRect = [statusItemView globalRect];
        statusRect.origin.y = NSMinY(statusRect) - NSHeight(statusRect) - 2 ;
    } else {
        statusRect.size = NSMakeSize(STATUS_ITEM_VIEW_WIDTH, [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness]);
        statusRect.origin.x = roundf((NSWidth(screenRect) - NSWidth(statusRect)) / 2);
        statusRect.origin.y = NSHeight(screenRect) - NSHeight(statusRect) * 2;
    }

    return statusRect;
}

- (void)setHasActivePanel:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (_hasActivePanel != flag)
    {
        _hasActivePanel = flag;

        if (_hasActivePanel)
        {
            [self openPanel];
        }
        else
        {
            [self closePanel];
        }
    }
}


- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self setHasActivePanel:NO];
}

- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[self window] isVisible]) {
        [self setHasActivePanel:NO];
    }
}

- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSWindow *panel = [self window];
    NSRect statusRect = [self statusRectForWindow:panel];
    NSRect panelRect = [panel frame];

    CGFloat statusX = roundf(NSMidX(statusRect));
    CGFloat panelX = statusX - NSMinX(panelRect);
    CGFloat maxX = NSMaxX([[self backgroundView] bounds]);
    CGFloat maxY = NSMaxY([[self backgroundView] bounds]);

    self.backgroundView.triangle = panelX; // @Jan: why is a setter method not possible (i.e. setTriangle)

    NSRect buttonRect = [[self buttonadd] frame];
    buttonRect.size.width = BUTTON_SIZE;
    buttonRect.size.height = buttonRect.size.width;
    buttonRect.origin.x = maxX - buttonRect.size.width;// * 1.5;
    buttonRect.origin.y = maxY - TRIANGLE_HEIGHT - buttonRect.size.height;// * 1.5;
    [[self buttonadd] setFrame:buttonRect];

//    NSRect listButtonRect = NSMakeRect(NSMinX([[self backgroundView] bounds]), buttonRect.origin.y, buttonRect.size.width, buttonRect.size.height) ;
//    [[self buttonlist] setFrame:listButtonRect];

    NSRect tableRect = [[self tableScrollView] frame];
    tableRect.size.width = maxX;
    tableRect.size.height = maxY - TRIANGLE_HEIGHT - buttonRect.size.height;
    tableRect.origin.x = self.backgroundView.frame.origin.x;
    tableRect.origin.y = maxY - POPUP_HEIGHT;

    [[self tableScrollView] setFrame:tableRect];
}

- (void)cancelOperation:(id)sender {
    [self setHasActivePanel:NO];
}

- (void)openPanel {
    NSWindow *panel = [self window];
    NSRect screenRect = [[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    NSRect statusRect = [self statusRectForWindow:panel];

    NSRect panelRect = [panel frame];
    panelRect.size.width = PANEL_WIDTH;
    panelRect.origin.x = roundf(NSMidX(statusRect) - NSWidth(panelRect) / 2);
    panelRect.origin.y = NSMaxY(statusRect) - NSHeight(panelRect);

    [panel setAlphaValue:0];
    [panel setFrame:statusRect display:YES];
    [panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    NSTimeInterval openDuration = OPEN_DURATION;

    // For testing
    NSEvent *currentEvent = [NSApp currentEvent];
    if ([currentEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown) {
        NSUInteger clearFlags = ([currentEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask); // @Jan
        BOOL shiftPressed = (clearFlags == NSShiftKeyMask);
        BOOL shiftOptionPressed = (clearFlags == (NSShiftKeyMask | NSAlternateKeyMask));
        if (shiftPressed || shiftOptionPressed) {
            openDuration *= 10;

            if (shiftOptionPressed)
                NSLog(@"Icon is at %@\n\tMenu is on screen %@\n\tWill be animated to %@",
                      NSStringFromRect(statusRect), NSStringFromRect(screenRect), NSStringFromRect(panelRect));
        }
    }

    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:openDuration];
    [[panel animator] setFrame:panelRect display:YES];
    [[panel animator] setAlphaValue:1];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

}

- (void)closePanel {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:CLOSE_DURATION];
    [[[self window] animator] setAlphaValue:0];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_walltime(NULL, NSEC_PER_SEC * CLOSE_DURATION * 2), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self window] orderOut:nil];
    });
}

- (NSColor*)colorForIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;

    NSInteger itemCount = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    float val = 0;

    float brightness = 0.63;

    if( itemCount < 11 )
    {
        val = brightness + ((0.1/10)*(index*3));
    }
    else
    {
        val = brightness + ((0.1/itemCount)*(index*(3)));
    }

    return [NSColor     colorWithDeviceHue: 0.57
                                saturation: 0.67
                                brightness: val
                                     alpha: 1
            ];
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
    didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView
           forRow:(NSInteger)row {
    rowView.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndex:row];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change
                        context:(void *)context {
    [statusItemView setStatusContent:[object valueForKeyPath:keyPath]];
}

@end
```

and here's the .h file:

```
//
//  UIController.h
//  hourglass
//
//  Created by Matze on 24/04/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 hourglass. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "GlobalProperties.h"
#import "StatusItemView.h"
#import "BackgroundView.h"
#import "RFOverlayScrollView.h"

@class UIController;

@protocol UIControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (StatusItemView *)statusItemViewForUIController:(UIController *)controller;

@end

@interface UIController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTableView *TableView;
    StatusItemView *statusItemView;
}

//TODO: Split Controller function for views into separate Controller Classes (i.e. BackgroundViewController)
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet BackgroundView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet RFOverlayScrollView *tableScrollView;

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *buttonadd;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *Tasks;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasActivePanel;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained, readonly) id<UIControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id<UIControllerDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)openPanel;
- (void)closePanel;
- (void)deleteSelectedObjects;
- (NSColor*)colorForIndex:(NSInteger)index;

- (IBAction)buttonDelete:(id)sender;


@end
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It will be nice if you set the record straight about your development before you mislead others.  Also, people are not going to read all your code lines.  You may want to short your code.

Comment: what do you mean by set the record straight about my development? That I am a bloody beginner?

Comment: "...keep calling each other creating an endless loop. But I can't figure out why". Could you show us the stack trace? At least we would know where to begin.

Comment: ok, I have logged the stack trace using `NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);` in the `awakeFromNib` method. As it's got 120 lines I have shared it [here](https://app.box.com/services/box_notes/2133/17126311422/639d50.e5ff310ddebf55648a07802018e242cc71c16e77c2683942756ac9c00308a11d?from_https=1&shared_name=04tsd5e3h3rcnwcmgrq1). The methods `- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification` and `- (void)awakeFromNib` are called all the time (using breakpoints).

Comment: here's a new link to the stack trace as the old one does not seem to work anymore:
https://gist.github.com/MatzeH/49e34802ba8a2bbbb375